# Swift: application(_: open url: options:) not being called at all

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, openurl

I'm trying to open a secondary view controller (not initial) in one app from a different app I built. So I'm trying to deep link to a view controller that's not the initial one, but the function is not being called at all.

I already implemented `openURLContexts`:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        print(URLContexts)
    }
```

Not being called:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    print(url)
    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
    let host = urlComponents?.host ?? ""
    print(host)

    if host == "accessPage" {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "jsonVC") as? JSONViewController
        window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
    return true
}
```

I added all the `info.plist` stuff and made sure `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` both return true.

Whenever I open the second app from the first one the primary view controller is always the one being displayed, not the one I want which is the `JSONViewController`.

Here's the code from the first app:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func accessButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        
        let secondAppPath = "second://accessPage"
        guard let appURL = URL(string: secondAppPath) else { return }
        
        if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
            application.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commented out the `SceneDelegate` file and deleted `ApplicationSceneManifest` in the `info.plist`, restarted Xcode and it worked just fine.